# how to rotate the camera in blender in a 360 fashion

Tags: camera

similar if not exactly like this video I attached. sorry in new to blender and would like to make my own anime

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sJ2cIj5Jlwk

Comment: Never use YouTube links to explain what you’re talking about unless absolutely necessary.

Comment: While files, images, and external links may be helpful additions to questions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload [images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [gifs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963), along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be searched for and indexed thus helping future users with similar issues find it.

Answer (score 1):

To make the camera’s rotation (or any animatable property of any object) change over time, keyframe it at one value on one frame, and then keyframe it at the target value on a later frame. Blender will interpolate between the keyframes automatically. This is the essence of 3D animation.

For more information, see [The Blender Manual,](http://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/index.html) or any of the [many resources online on the subject.](http://duckduckgo.com/?q=animating%20in%20blender)